# Mathematica function/package for shuffle permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

Does anyone knows a way to compute a list of all (p,q)-shuffles in mathematica?

For a definition of the shuffle permutations see for example http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/shuffle

I'm dreaming of a function with p and q as arguments that gives me:

1.) The number of all (p,q)-shuffles.

2.) A list of the actual "shuffle" (p+q)-permutations

3.) The sign of each such permutation

Comment: Let's see if we can do better than this http://mathhelpforum.com/math-software/81970-p-q-shuffle-mathematica.html

Comment: Ok. Since this was asked before, I guess there is no such thing.

Comment: But it was not asked _here_ :D

Comment: Is there a package to work with general permutations? Then maybe I can use it as a starting point to write that function by myself.

Comment: Very painfully inefficient: `With[{p = 4, q = 5}, Union[Join[Sort[Take[#, p]], Sort[Take[#, -q]]] & /@ Permutations[Range[p + q]]]]`

Comment: Also: look up the `Signature[]` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) The number of all (p,q) shuffles is

```
Binomial[p+q,p]
```

[since when you chose the first p elements, the whole thing (and its order) is given.](http://planetmath.org/?op=getobj&from=objects&id=4176)

2)The actual shuffles are given by: (See JM's comment below*)

```
With[{x = Range@#1}, {#, Complement[x, #]} & /@ Subsets[x, {#2}]] &[p + q, p]
```

Example:

```
p = 3; q = 2;
With[{x = Range@#1}, {#, Complement[x, #]} & /@ Subsets[x, {#2}]] &[p + q, p]

(*
->
{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5}}, 
 {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {1, 5}}, {{2, 3, 5}, {1, 4}}, 
 {{2, 4, 5}, {1, 3}}, {{3, 4, 5}, {1, 2}}}
```

3) The sign of each permutation (for the above shuffles) is given by:

```
Signature/@ With[{x=Range@#1}, Join[#, Complement[x, #]] & /@ Subsets[x, {#2}]] &[p+q,p]
```

Example:

```
p = 3; q = 2;
Signature/@ With[{x=Range@#1}, Join[#, Complement[x, #]] & /@ Subsets[x, {#2}]] &[p+q,p]
(*
-> {1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1}
*)
```

Comment: mmm looking again ... all those p+q looks nasty. Lets see if I can improve

Comment: `Signature[]` is built-in; no need for an auxiliary package...

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I keep using Combinatorica ... old vice. Editing.

Comment: On that note: it might be a bit better if you don't generate `Range[p + q]` more than once: `With[{pq = Range[p + q]}, Join[#, Complement[pq, #]] & /@ Subsets[pq, {p}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. yep. I'm trying to keep it as a one liner function of p,q

Comment: Wow! I didn't expected that. great job!

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus As I said ... it was not asked here before